# How to assign a multi-dimensional array to a temporary variable?

Tags: c++

I want to assign a statically allocated, multi-dimensional array to a temporary variable. Consider the following example:

```
void foo(int b[3][2])
{
    b[1][1] = 1; // no segmentation fault
}

int main()
{
    int a[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {11, 12}, {21, 22}};

    foo(a);

    int** c;
    c = (int**)&a;
    c[1][1] = 1; // segmentation fault on execution

    int* d[3];
    d[0] = (int*)&(a[0]);
    d[1] = (int*)&(a[1]);
    d[2] = (int*)&(a[2]);
    d[1][1] = 1; // no segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I want to do what the compiler does with the parameter `b` of `foo()`. But the only working solution I could come up with is `d`. Is there no less complicated way?

Comment: It's strange how many people think a 2D array somehow casts directly to a pointer to pointers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare+b+as+pointer+to+array+2+of+int) ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++decl)) is your friend:

```
cdecl> explain int b[3][2]
declare b as array 3 of array 2 of int
cdecl> declare b as pointer to array 2 of int
int (*b)[2]
```

So, try this:

```
void foo(int b[3][2])
{
    b[1][1] = 1; // no segmentation fault
}

int main()
{
    int a[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {11, 12}, {21, 22}};

    foo(a);

    int (*b)[2] = a;

    b[1][1] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: huh - that's new. where/what is cdecl?

Comment: OMG _cdecl_ :D:D:D I have never seen this :D There's online version: @sehe - http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 9):

`int[3][2]` and `int**` are incompatible types. You cannot cast one to another.

Try this:

```
int (*c)[2];
c = a; //no need to cast 
c[1][1] = 1; //ok
```

Or you could do this (declaration as well as initialization):

```
int (*c)[2] = a; //no need to cast 
c[1][1] = 1; //ok
```

---

**Thumb of rule:**

- Don't use c-style cast in C++.  Use C++-style cast. Had you used C++-style cast, the compiler would have told you the problem much before ([ideone](http://ideone.com/x3Ziv)) (no need to run the code to see the problem):

  ```
  prog.cpp:5: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘int (*)[3][2]’ to type ‘int**’
  ```

  But C-style cast compiles it fine ([ideone](http://ideone.com/HpW1o)), as you already know.
- And whenever you use cast, even C++-style cast, your first doubt should be the cast itself if the program doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

As you are probably aware now, from the other answers, the type of `a` is not actually equivalent to `int**` - it jsut *decays* to that (when returned/passed by value).

```
int (*b)[2] = a; // would solve that
```

There is a more C++ way:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> M23;

void foo(M23& b)
{
    b[1][1] = 1; 
}

int main()
{
    M23 a = {{1, 2}, {11, 12}, {21, 22}};

    foo(a);

    M23 d = a;
    d[1][1] = 1;
}
```

Comment: @sehe: This is good, but you should also answer the question, and explain the problem with OP's code. Once you explained that, you can suggest better alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a pretty modern compiler that supports enough parts of the C++11 standard, you can use `auto`:

```
int a[3][2] = ...;
auto &b = a;
b[1][1] = 1;  // a[1][1] will be set
```

Of course, both `a` and `b` has to be defined in the same scope for it to work. You can't have an `auto` parameter in a function for example (that's what templates are for.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast explicitly, so try writing

```
 c = &a;
```

Then the GCC compiler (using `gcc -Wall -g bidim.c -o bidim` to compile) gives you the correct warning:

```
bidim.c:13:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

And then you should realize that a 2D matrix is not implemented as an array of pointers to 1D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes into my mind is using a typedef and reference like

```
typedef int thing_t[3][2];
thing_t& e = a;
e[1][1] = 1;
```

With pointers

```
int (*f)[2] = a;
f[1][1] = 1;
```

Another possibility is to encapsulate it in `struct`.