# Are the parentheses required when declaring a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I was just looking at this question:

[How to assign a multi-dimensional array to a temporary variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213338/how-to-assign-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-temporary-variable)

The solution ended up using the lines:

```
int a[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {11, 12}, {21, 22}};
...
int (*b)[2] = a;
```

to "assign a statically allocated, multi-dimensional array to a temporary variable."

I'm a little confused about the syntax of the line:

```
int (*b)[2] = a;
```

In this instance, are the parentheses required to get the right effect, and if so, why?  Is there a way to get the same result without using them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
int (*b)[2]
```

declares `b` as a pointer to an array of two `int`s.  This is not the same as:

```
int *b[2]
```

which declares `b` as an array of two pointers-to-`int`.

You need the first form in order to correctly perform pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I can never keep that straight in my mind.

Comment: Yeah, I was just checking that out from the other question actually - it's a  pretty cool tool.